# Is there a contradiction in the description of the 4-vector french page of wikipedia?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors

In french wikipedia of 4-vector :

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrivecteur#De_la_base_covariante_aux_quadrivecteurs_covariants

The description starts with an explanation, in context of special relativity, for the dot product :
(let's call this part (A)) :
"
$<u;v> = \sum_{i,j=0}^{3} u_i.v^j <e^i,e_j> = \sum_{i,j=0}^{3} u_i.v^j.\delta^i_j = \sum_{i=0}^{3} u_i.v^i = u_i.v^i$
"

Then, they describe the case of general relativity and they state that it is the **same method**. They write (let's call this part (B)) :

"
$<u;v> = \sum_{i,j=0}^{3} g_{ij}.u^i.v^j = g_{ij}.u^i.v^j$

where the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ has been introduced.
$<e^i;e_j> = \delta^i_j$

They state also $e^i = g^{ij}e_j$ and $u_i = g_{ij}u^j$

"

Now let's analyse : let's start again from A which states : $<u;v> = \sum_{i,j=0}^{3} u_i.v^j.\delta^i_j$

This is different to (B) : $<u;v> = \sum_{i,j=0}^{3} g_{ij}.u^i.v^j$

**since $g_{ij}$ is not equal to $\delta^i_j$**.

Is there a contradiction in the description of the 4-vector french page of wikipedia ?

What is missing to make the agreement between the two parts ? (the metric tensor do exist in special relativity as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the two are different because $g_{ij} \neq \delta^i_j$, but this is because they are different that $A$ and $B$ are the same : $u_i = g_{ik}u^k$. Then :
\begin{equation}
u_i v^j \delta^i_j = g_{ik}u^k v^j \delta^i_j = u^k v^j \times (g_{ik}\delta^i_j) = u^k v^j \times g_{ij}
\end{equation}

Comment: A huge thanks for your great help